# Selected Items per listbox instead of all selected items in one listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

My listbox is selecting the values correctly, but it is separating the values per listbox instead of inserting all of the values in one list box.

Why is this behavior happening?

Code Behind

```
protected void GvInBlocks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                //Find listBoxCourse in GvChildBlock
                ListBox listBoxCourse = e.Row.FindControl("listBoxCourse") as ListBox;
                getCourseLB(listBoxCourse);

                //Fill control
                string CourseNames = (e.Row.FindControl("lblChildBlockCourse") as Label).Text;
                list.Add(CourseNames);

                foreach(ListItem items in listBoxCourse.Items)
                {
                    if(list.Contains(items.Value))
                    {
                        items.Selected = true;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

MarkUp Language

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlInBlocks" runat="server" Style="display: none">
<asp:GridView ID="GvInBlocks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="list" OnRowDataBound="GvInBlocks_RowDataBound">

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Curso">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblChildBlockCourse" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseID") %>' Visible = "false" />
<asp:ListBox ID="listBoxCourse" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I edited the code and I did separate the values by a comma but the results remain the same , is it because of the RowDataBound? If the database returns 2 rows is it going to return 2 list boxes?
Code Edited:

```
//Find listBoxCourse in GvChildBlock
                ListBox listBoxCourse = e.Row.FindControl("listBoxCourse") as ListBox;
                getCourseLB(listBoxCourse);

                //Fill control
                string CourseNames = (e.Row.FindControl("lblChildBlockCourse") as Label).Text;
                string[] arrayNames = CourseNames.Split(',');

                foreach(var names in arrayNames)
                {
                    listBoxCourse.Items.FindByValue(names).Selected = true;
                }
```

Comment: string CourseNames = (e.Row.FindControl("lblChildBlockCourse") as Label).Text;  FindControl looks like it is returning multiple items that you convert to a string so it is creating the string with each returned item separated by commas.

Comment: You have to separate the items. See what FindControl is returning and you should be able to do a foreach loop on them. Not enough time to do it myself. I can probably look at it later if someone else hasn't answered by then.

Comment: is values/text in that label delimited some how?

Comment: Now that I checked , the values inside the label aren't delimited with any commas or so

Comment: @OldDog Check the edit that I did in this post above.

Answer (score 0):

So the course list is like say:

```
Physics 204, Math 220, Computing 220
```

So, then you need to split above into a "list" for the listbox

eg:
//Fill control

```
 string CourseNames = (e.Row.FindControl("lblChildBlockCourse") as Label).Text;
 CourseNames = CourseNames.Repace(", ",","); ' remove blanks

 List<string> slCourse = (List<string>)CourseNames.Split(',').ToList();
 listBoxCourse.DataSource = slCourse;
 listBoxCourse.DataBind();
```

Now, your list box is filled up with values.

Or is there  a 100% separate list of choices that supposed to drive the listbox, and you only want to select/set ONE course name as the selected value in listbox?

Ok, for some VERY strange design, we should have this setup:

[image]

You have some students, a table of the coures they are taking, and the 3rd table is really just a list of all courses.

but, for some strange reason, we don't have the courses table, and have this:

[image]

Worse, we some how have "one" column that has the list of "id" the student is taking (again, breaks every rule - makes ANY kind of solution very difficult).

And even worse yet? The desired output is to display ALL courses for each row, and ONLY highlight the one the student is enrolled.

Seems to me that that each row should ONLY show their courses, and not all of them, and then in that list show the highlighted ones.

But, lets go with this "VERY strange from another planet question that does not make sense to do it this way.

So, we have to fill up the grid, (easy). We also have to drop in a listbox of ALL COURSES.

So, lets do this part first, and THEN we work on the highlight part.

So, we have this grid - a few columns, and list box

```
    <div style="width:40%;padding:35px">

        <asp:GridView ID="GVStudents" runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="GVStudents_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"    HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"     HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseIDList" HeaderText="CourseIDList" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Courses" HeaderStyle-Width="190px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="LstCourses" runat="server" Style="Height:120px;width:170px"
                            DataValueField ="ID"
                            DataTextField ="Course">
                        </asp:ListBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Ok, now the code to fill this up:

```
public partial class StudentListBox1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable rstCourses = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();

    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        rstCourses = MyRst("SELECT ID, Course from Courses ORDER BY Course");
        // load grid
        GVStudents.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM Students Order by FirstName");
        GVStudents.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GVStudents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // for each row, load up listbox with courses
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ListBox lv = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("LstCourses");
            lv.DataSource = rstCourses;
            lv.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And now out output is this:

[image]

So the next bit of code would be to take that id list from that one column, and high light the courses in the course listbox. (and if that works, then we can remove the "id list" row in that grid. So, lets write that part to highlight the courses.

The code would/could be:

(we add right after the databind code that filled the listbox.

So we now from above have this:

```
    protected void GVStudents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // for each row, load up listbox with courses
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ListBox lv = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("LstCourses");
            lv.DataSource = rstCourses;
            lv.DataBind();

            // get "item list" column (we NOT use from grid, since we plan to remove
            // from grid display - so, get this from the data source
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            List<string> sIdList = gData["CourseIDList"].ToString().Split(' ').ToList();

            foreach (ListItem lBox in lv.Items)
            {
                lBox.Selected = sIdList.Contains(lBox.Value);
            } 
        }
    }
```

And now we have this output:

[image]

Now, it does seem to me, it would be better to show JUST the courses they have in each list box.

On the other hand, I suppose we could start using the above to tick off (select more courses for each user). And we could use the above grid for this.

***Edit ===========================================***

Ok, so we now have more information and that each row DOES NOT have a list of courses as "id" separated by some delimited.

so, we can dump the id list list column, and now have just student information in the one line + a list box of courses like this:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GVStudents" runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="GVStudents_RowDataBound" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"    HeaderText="FirstName"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"     HeaderText="LastName"  />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Courses" HeaderStyle-Width="190px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="LstCourses" runat="server" Style="Height:120px;width:170px"
                        DataValueField ="ID"
                        DataTextField ="Course"
                        SelectionMode="Multiple"
                        SelectMethod="">
                    </asp:ListBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And now our code to fill out the list box becomes this:

```
   protected void GVStudents_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // for each row, load up listbox with courses
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ListBox lv = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("LstCourses");
            lv.DataSource = rstCourses;
            lv.DataBind();

            // now get all courses for this student

            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            int StudentPK = (int)gData["ID"];
            
            DataTable rstStudentCourses;
            string strSQL = "SELECT Course_ID FROM StudentCourses WHERE Student_ID = " + StudentPK;
            rstStudentCourses = MyRst(strSQL);
           
            foreach (ListItem lBox in lv.Items)
            {
                string sFind = "Course_ID = " + lBox.Value;
                lBox.Selected = (rstStudentCourses.Select(sFind).Count() > 0);
            } 
        }
```

And out output is this:

[image]

As noted, it might be better for each row to ONLY show the courses taken, and not just highlight out of ALL possible courses.

Of course this is a easy change, and we would DUMP the global scoped courses datatable, and simple pull course list for each row, and directly fill the list box with those courses (it would be less code, since no matching loop against the whole course list in the list box would now be required. (but just  query to fill listbox with ONLY courses for the one row/student).

Comment: The variable course names are just ID's ,  yet these ID's don't have a comma to separate them. The selected values of the listbox can be multiple values , these values come from a database.

Comment: Check my edit above in the post.

Comment: Did you have the time to check it out? @Albert D. Kallal?

Comment: Sure, take a look at my edit. I show how to have a list box in the grid, and then how to selected each "id" to the list box.  I am kind of thinking it would  be better to just show what courses they have in the list box in place of highlighting which ones they have, but regardless - see my edit and how this works.

Comment: Okay , got almost all of it, but I can't do it like you did in the column "CourseIDList" how did you manage to insert all of the ID's inside one single row? My grid is creating a row for each "CourseIDList"

Comment: because you told everyone and made it crystal clear that's what you have quote->I edited the code and I did separate the values by a comma.  ------- We then asked for more information, then you told us the delimiter used is NOT  ",", but was in fact a space. quote->he values inside the label aren't delimited with any commas or so ----- AGAIN you stated values in that one row/label. You did not state VALUE but outright used the term VALUES. When we asked what kind of delimiter, we asked if that delimiter is a "," or a space. So now you telling us that you don't have VALUES but have ONE value?

Comment: So your answer should have been, no, the label does not contain values, but has one value per row. So, for my example, I made up that column since we ALL BASED on what you made crystal clear - that the VALUES (not value) in that label are delimited. Now that this massive huge detail been cleared up? Then why do you have a whole new row for each student and course? You want ONE row for each student, and then for each row, you will pull in their student list. for that row. So we can dump the id "list" for each row, and use a query for that row to pull in the student courses they have.

Comment: What this suggests is that you DO HAVE  good database design, and thus you are using a sql join of students and courses. You don't want that. You drive the grid with ONLY a row from students table, and leave out the courses table in that sql join. So now we ONLY get rows in the grid for EACH student, and ONLY one for for each student. We then on our data bound fill the list box with a query in place of that fake ID list I made up for this example. And thus you VERY much like have the original related tables like we expect. So, just replace the code for the "id list" to query pulling courses.

Comment: I have multiple ID's of multiple courses not just one , I was just asking how did you manage to insert all of the ID's in ONE Single row of the gridview like you posted an image of "1 2 3 5". How did you do that ? My id's are being separated by each row of the gridview !

Comment: Like I stated, I made that column up - since no one on planet earth would do things that way. So, it looks like we can assume that for each student, you DO HAVE a child table of courses they have taken. As I stated, that means we can NOW dump that made up column, since that is NOT what you have. So, we have a a row for one student, and now we want a list of the courses - see my edit to the post and my 2nd example that shows how this works.

Comment: Yes , I do have a column that has all the ID's of all the courses taken by a student(following your example to make it easier for us), yet these ID's are obviously coming from a database, so they come separate by rows. I think the problem is : If there are 2 or more ID's coming from a database the grid will create a row for each ID. What I want to do is take all of the ID's coming from a database and put it all together in a single row and then with those ID's fill up the listbox.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, so you don't have a label with VALUES but have a row. As noted, your query driving the grid thus "must" be a join between students and courses, and then of course you get mutliple rows for each student. As I stated, you want to drive the grid ONLY with the students data source - not a sql join. So your question really was this: I want to display one row of data (each student), and in the one student row, I want to fill a list box with their courses taken from the courses table. (how hard was that question? ). So there is ZERO reason to have multiple rows for one student.

Comment: Separated by row, and separated by a delimiter is a HUGE LARGE MASSIVE and a Mount Everest of a different answer. Anyway, as noted, for no reason should the query that drives the grid have anything more then just rows of data from students. The fact that we THEN wish to pull in multiple rows for the listbox is of course a 2nd goal, but that grid can only display one row for each student, and thus since that's what you need and want, then build a query that only drives the grid with one row per student. Then we use the data bound row event to process in the child records into that listbox

Comment: I saw your edit and my god... It is still not working , I did exactly like you posted and it still displaying in each listbox per row like I printed in the original question. Right now , At this point, I really don't know what am I doing wrong... Thank you for your help once again.

Comment: I will think of a different approach. Thank you very much for your help !!